# Variant form of the gronwall inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, inequalities

I know the following statement for gronwall inequality: 
Given $f$ non negative and absolutely continuous on $[0;T]$ and $\phi \in L^1(0;T)$if we have,
$f' \leq \phi f$ and $f(0)=0$ then $f=0$

Now is it still true if we have $f'(t) \leq \phi(t) sup_{s \in [0;t]}f(s)$ ?

In fact I have an inequality that looks like this:
$f(t) \leq \int_0^t \phi(s)sup_{x \in [0;s]}f(x) ds$ and I was wondering if i could still deduce that f is 0

Thanks for any response if anyone did already encounter this !

Comment: Define $F(t)=\max_{0\le s\le t}f(s)$. Then it's "clear" that $F'(t)=0$ or $=f'(t)$, so $F'\le \phi F$, and thus $F\equiv 0$. The only (hopefully small) technical problem here is to establish that $F\in AC$ also, but that sounds right.

Comment: $F\in AC$ is in fact obvious as $F(b)-F(a)$ is estimated by the total variation of $f$ on this interval, which is an AC measure by assumption.

Comment: That seems correct, I will have to work out all the details but everything seems good. Thank you for your answer !